# Volume of Shape

Tags: calculus, integration, cross-sections

The base is the semicircle $$y=\sqrt{16−x^2},$$
where -4 $\le$ $x$ $\le$ 4. The cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are squares.
$$\\$$
So far this is what I have:

$\int (Area)\,dx$

$\implies$ $\int \frac{π}{2} ($$r^2$$)\ dx$.

$r$ = $\frac{\sqrt{16−x^2}}{2}$

$\implies$ $ \frac {π}{8}$ $\int 16- $$x^2$$\ dx$.
$$\\$$
I'm confused with what I have to do with the information given about the squares.

Comment: I approached this question using the area for a semicircle

Comment: What's the 'radius' of a square in terms of the circle?

Comment: https://youtu.be/_jx5pbKIzaM just because it's this exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the area of a square.

Remember that the area of a square is $s^2$.

For this problem, your side length is $y=\sqrt{16−x^2}$, which means your area for the square is $y=\sqrt{16−x^2}^2.$
$$\\$$

$$\int_{-4}^{4}{16 +x^2 } \,dx$$
$$\\$$
Can you continue from there?

Comment: yes, so it would be 16x+(x^3/3) then I plug in the limits

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2):

Each slice of the solid is a square.

The side length of the square is equal to the height of the function at that point.

So each square has area $(\sqrt{16-x^2})^2=16-x^2$.

You just need to integrate $\displaystyle \int_{-4}^4 (16-x^2)\,dx=\boxed{\frac{256}{3}}$.

Note, the base is the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ AND $y=0$.

Therefore, the side of the square at each point would be the distance between the two curves.

Comment: I believe you're missing a constant of 2 for the length which affects the area by 4.

Comment: but its a semicircle, not a circle. @ElSpiffy

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: Why is the $\sqrt{16−x^2},$ the length of the square?

Comment: because the cross sections are perpendicular to the x-axis. so it's like if you put your finger perpendicular to the x axis, and measure the distance from y=0 to y=$\sqrt{16-x^2}$, and construct a square with your finger as the length and an extending height above the paper

Comment: try to visualize it, look at some diagrams online. this concept becomes 100x easier if you can imagine it in your head or draw a little picture

Comment: okay, but can you explain why we don't use the area for a semicircle? I'm a bit confused

Comment: i'll try my best. the semicircle is the base. we are squeezing together a bunch of different sized squares ON the semicircular base to get a solid. so the semicircle describes the base, and for each x, you can measure the distance between y=0 and y=$\sqrt{16-x^2}$ because it is a square, that will be equal to the height, so $16-x^2$ is equal to the area of the square slice, for each x. and if we integrate that from -4 to 4, we get the volume of the solid

Comment: okay that makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: also, if it said perpendicular to the y-axis do we put everything in terms of y?

Comment: yes we would. because we would find all our dimensions in terms of that y-length. @AmR

Answer (score 1):

You should be considering the slice which is square in shape. Imagine a vertical line drawn at some point $x$ that meets the semi-circle.  This will be the side of your square slice. Note the length of this line is simply the $y-$value of the point where the line meets the semicircle.

Now compute the area of this square slice as $y^2$. Let $dx$ be the thickness of this slice.

The volume of this square slice is $y^2 \, dx$.

So the total volume is
$$\int_{-4}^{4} y^2 \, dx.$$